# SDcard only RO even after set permissions

Tags: android

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to Manifest but I still get "SDcard mounted RO" when executing the below code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
                ("SDcard not mounted"));
    }
    else if (!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
                ("SDcard mounted RO"));
    }
    else {
        Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
                ("SDcard mounted RW"));
    }
```

Comment: Can you copy files to sdcard via file explore?

Comment: sdcard is mounted rw in file explorers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code logic seems to be wrong?

```
if(!extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
            ("SDcard not mounted"));
}
else ...
```

"Not equal to MEDIA_MOUNTED" could be "mounted_ro" or "not mounted"...

Anyway, you should change to ...

```
if(extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
            ("SDcard mounted RW"));

}
else if (extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
            ("SDcard mounted RO"));
}
else {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
            ("SDcard not mounted"));
}
```